# images in assets

Tags: java, android, file, storage

I have a folder in res with the name of "frame" it contains image i want to get all the images in that folder and put in my external storage . 
 This is my directory:

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "assets" instead of "res".  The "res" gets changed when your app is compiled and the contents are put into a structure that resembles nothing of what it looked like in your project.  However, "assets" stays the same and is not touched.  You can access these with the AssetsManager : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html